# ftrace on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kernel, mount, debug

I wish to work with ftrace on ubuntu and able to use **trace-cmd** (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/trace-cmd-start.1.html).

But as per this http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/, I want to manually access `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing` section.

```
 $ cd /sys/kernel/debug/
-bash: cd: /sys/kernel/debug/: Permission denied
```

**debugfs** in mounted.

```
 $ mount |grep debugfs
15:nodev on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
```

Please share your knowledge.

Comment: Procedure explained here http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.com/2014/05/ftrace-kernel-function-tracer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the debugfs requires root privileges. To open a root shell, open a normal shell and run

```
$ sudo -i
```

You will be asked for your password, then be given a root shell. In that shell, you can `cd` to `/sys/kernel/debug`.